# Laravel Select Fields from Two different Table as per Condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, eloquent

I have 3 tables (members, members3, payout)

Payout Table having records with the relationship of both other tables (members, members3)

I want to list the records with both table relationships.

***For example:***

**Members Table (Plan 1)** 
id, name, mobile 
1, Karthik, 9237493

**Members3 Table (plan 3)** 
id, name, mobile 
1, George, 923143422

**Payout Table** 
id, mem_id, plan_id, Amount 
1, 1, 1, 500 
2, 1, 3, 1500

***I want to fetch the records as below:*** 
ID, Member, Amount
1, Karthik, 500 
2, George, 1500

I have something already done it my Laravel Code. But Can't fetch the select fields as per relationship modal.

```
$payout=Payout::leftJoin('tbl_members', function($join){
        $join->on('tbl_payout.mem_id', '=', 'tbl_members.id')
        ->where('tbl_payout.plan_id', '=', '1');
        })       
        ->leftJoin('tbl_members3', function($join){
        $join->on('tbl_payout.mem_id', '=', 'tbl_members3.id')
        ->where('tbl_payout.plan_id', '=', '3');
        })       
->Select(DB::Raw('tbl_payout.mem_id, tbl_members.username, tbl_members.name, tbl_payout.paid, tbl_members.city, tbl_members.mobile, tbl_members.bank, tbl_members.bank_number, tbl_members.bank_branch, tbl_members.bank_ifsc'))
->get();
```

In this Query, Eloquent fetches the tbl_members records only not tbl_members3 records.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: Since you have the purchased plan ID in the payouts table, You can combine the member tables into one table and easily query those data.

Comment: @Harshana look at the above query. it fetches table 1 only. Give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your join query at `tbl_members.id` you need to use `tbl_members3` instead of `tbl_members`

And you need to use inner join to get data from both tables `tbl_members` and `tbl_members3`

```
  $payout=Payout::Select(DB::Raw('tbl_payout.mem_id, name, tbl_payout.paid, tbl_members.city, tbl_members.mobile, tbl_members.bank, tbl_members.bank_number, tbl_members.bank_branch, tbl_members.bank_ifsc'))
    ->join('tbl_members', function($join){
    $join->on('tbl_payout.mem_id', '=', 'tbl_members.id')
    ->where('tbl_payout.plan_id', '=', '1');
    })       
    ->join('tbl_members3', function($join){
    $join->on('tbl_payout.mem_id', '=', 'tbl_members3.id')
    ->where('tbl_payout.plan_id', '=', '3');
    })       
->get();
```

Comment: Its ok. I fixed it right now. But the question is how can i select fields from both members and members3 table. look at the select query line.

Comment: you need to use inner join

Answer (score 0):

in your model

```
 class Payout extends Model
 {
     public function member()
     {
         if ($this->plan_id == 1) {
             return $this->belongsTo(Members::class, 'mem_id');
         } else if ($this->plan_id == 3) {
             return $this->belongsTo(Members3::class, 'mem_id');
         }
     }
 }
```

fetch data:

```
$payouts = Payout::with('member')->get();
foreach($payouts as $payout) {
    $id = $payout->id;
    $name = $payout->member->name;
    $amount = $payout->amount;
}
```